# Delay in loading Html Page(WebView) from assets folder in real android device

Tags: android, html, android-webview, android-assets, timedelay

***WebView takes approx. 10 second time to load Html Page from `Assets` folder in real android device greater than 4.3....***
*My WebView activity are as follows:-*

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.os.Build;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

 public class Activity_WebView extends ActionBarActivity {

boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_webview);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    TextView app_Title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    app_Title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String TITLE = intent.getStringExtra("Title");
    String URL_PATH = intent.getStringExtra("Url_Path");

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 14) {
            webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}



    GlobalVariablesCollection.globalPD = CustomProgressBarDialog.showProgressDialog(Activity_WebView.this);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

    app_Title.setText(TITLE);
    webview.loadUrl(URL_PATH);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!loadingFinished) {
                redirect = true;
            }

            loadingFinished = false;
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
            loadingFinished = false;
            //SHOW LOADING IF IT IS NOT ALREADY VISIBLE
            GlobalVariablesCollection.globalPD.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (!redirect) {
                loadingFinished = true;
            }

            if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
                //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
                GlobalVariablesCollection.globalPD.dismiss();

            } else {
                redirect = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage(description);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

My Requirement:
**WebView should display Html Page on**

> onPageFinished